# Javascript image dropdown set background color

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to use in an html page, generated from PHP, the combobox like in Java. 
I want to add an icon, some text, some additional text and a background color.
The data can ben generated from a JSON file or with a query in PHP, from a MySQL DB. I've found this very powerful [solution](https://github.com/marghoobsuleman/ms-Dropdown), which can be a good starting point. The only problem I'm not able to fix, it is about the background color of the select/li. In fact, I want that they are different from white, and are related with a variable, which is present in the JSON file. How Can I set the background color of each select, dynamically with the actual code ?

[image]

**UPDATE**

Here is the code:

```
form action="submitdata.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="frmdata">

        <select id="payments" name="payments" style="width:250px;">

            <option class="green" value="140" data-image="./squadre/par.png" data-description="Titolare vs SAM">MIRANTE</option>
            <option class="green" value="156" data-image="./squadre/rom.png" data-description="Titolare vs SAM">SKORUPSKI</option>
            <option class="orange" value="124" data-image="./squadre/rom.png" data-description="Panchina vs SAM">DE SANCTIS</option>

        </select> &nbsp;

    </form>
    <p>
        &nbsp;
    </p>

    <script>
        //var tc;
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $("#payments").msDropdown({
                visibleRows : 4
            });

        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can style the background color of the items with:

```
.ddChild li._msddli_ { background-color: #c00; }
```

You will likely want to include a CSS selector for the specific dropdown you want to style. In that case, replace the `.ddChild` with the id of dropdown to be styled.

For the payment example shown here: http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/index.html, something like this would do the trick:

```
#payments_msdd li._msddli_ { background-color: #FFA600; }
```

You can also style based on enabled/disabled:

```
#payments_msdd li._msddli_.enabled { background-color: #FFA600; }
#payments_msdd li._msddli_.disabled { background-color: #CCC; }
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean to add a specif class for the <option>, with a echo under PHP, in according the color of the background I want ?

Comment: No, definitely not the `option`, maybe the `select`. However, it looks like you already need to have an id on the `select` to get that jQuery plugin to work. So, just reuse that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you post some code ? Suppose that I want 3 class (green, orange and red). How Can I set the background for each option of the drop list ?

Comment: I need you to post a link or some code first. I'm just basing my answer off of the example on the website you provided. You should take a look at the example link I included and compare that with your own code to see where they match up.

Comment: I have posted the example code. By the class, I want that background color.